# Using Boost ICL to Find All Objects Whose Range Contains a Point

Tags: c++, boost, intervals

I am given a list L of objects, each which contain a time added, a time removed, a name, and some other fields.  Given a time T, I want to return a list that only contains objects from L where T falls between the object's time added and time removed (additionally, I would like to search for all objects of a particular name at the same time but its not necessary if it complicates things).  How would I go about doing this with Boost's ICL?

Comment: I am a noobie to boost and templates in general so if possible please give me an example and don't try to immediately teach me theory (I like to learn it after I understand the example) as I don't understand the docs which is why I came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your object looks like

```
struct record {
    std::string name;

    using ptime = boost::posix_time::ptime;
    ptime added, removed;
};
```

Now, let's add a convenience method so we can work easier with the time intervals:

```
    icl::interval<ptime>::interval_type validity() const { 
        icl::interval<ptime> x;
        return x.right_open(added, removed);
    }
```

A simple test program looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    ptime const start(day_clock::local_day(), { });

    std::vector<record> L {
        { "long"     , start + hours(77) , start + days(7) }   ,
        { "medium"   , start + hours(200), start + hours(236) },
        { "short"    , start + hours(220), start + hours(226) },
        { "ephemeral", start + hours(100), start + hours(101) },
    };

    for (ptime T = start; T <= (start + days(10)); T += hours(6))
    {
        std::cout << "\nT:" << T << "\t";
        std::ostream_iterator<record> out(std::cout, ";");
        std::copy_if(L.begin(), L.end(), out, [T](record const& r) { return icl::contains(r.validity(), T); });
    }
}
```

It iterates a timepoint `T` through a range of 10 days in steps of 6 hours, and prints the matching objects from `L`, see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caef80a679cbf380)**

```
T:2014-Jun-06 00:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-06 06:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-06 12:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-06 18:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-07 00:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-07 06:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-07 12:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-07 18:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-08 00:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-08 06:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-08 12:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-08 18:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-09 00:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-09 06:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-09 12:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-09 18:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-10 00:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-10 06:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-10 12:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-10 18:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-11 00:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-11 06:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-11 12:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-11 18:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-12 00:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-12 06:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-12 12:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-12 18:00:00  {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-13 00:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-13 06:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-13 12:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-13 18:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-14 00:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-14 06:00:00  
T:2014-Jun-14 12:00:00  {medium, 2014-Jun-14 08:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 20:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-14 18:00:00  {medium, 2014-Jun-14 08:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 20:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-15 00:00:00  {medium, 2014-Jun-14 08:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 20:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-15 06:00:00  {medium, 2014-Jun-14 08:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 20:00:00};{short, 2014-Jun-15 04:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 10:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-15 12:00:00  {medium, 2014-Jun-14 08:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 20:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-15 18:00:00  {medium, 2014-Jun-14 08:00:00, 2014-Jun-15 20:00:00};
T:2014-Jun-16 00:00:00
```

As you can see, `"ephemeral"` is so short, it gets completely missed using this approach! You might want to traverse time in *slots*, rather than *timepoints* stepwise:

```
for (auto Slot = icl::interval<ptime>::right_open(start, start + hours(6));
     Slot.lower() <= (start + days(10)); 
     Slot = icl::interval<ptime>::right_open(Slot.upper(), Slot.upper() + hours(6)))
{
    std::cout << "\nSlot:" << Slot << "\t";
    std::ostream_iterator<record> out(std::cout, ";");
    std::copy_if(L.begin(), L.end(), out, [Slot](record const& r) { return icl::intersects(Slot, r.validity()); });
}
```

See that **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b974b24b0378b31)** too, and observe how `"ephemeral"` is no longer missed:

```
...
Slot:[2014-Jun-09 18:00:00,2014-Jun-10 00:00:00)    {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
Slot:[2014-Jun-10 00:00:00,2014-Jun-10 06:00:00)    {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};{ephemeral, 2014-Jun-10 04:00:00, 2014-Jun-10 05:00:00};
Slot:[2014-Jun-10 06:00:00,2014-Jun-10 12:00:00)    {long, 2014-Jun-09 05:00:00, 2014-Jun-13 00:00:00};
...
```